# Debugger not working with netbeans + wampserver

Tags: php, netbeans, windows-7, wamp, xdebug

I have configured xdebug in wamp+netbeans. It installed properly and in `phpinfo()` it showing xdebug configuration information. But still I am not able to debug my application with it.

Sometimes it shows the `waiting for connection` error. Sometimes it doesn't show it but also not stopped on given breakpoints.

```
Following is my configuration :

PHP Version 5.3.9

PHP Extension Build API20090626, TS, VC9

In D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll

xdebug version: (in phpinfo)
Version     2.2.1
IDE Key     netbeans-xdebug

In php.ini file

[xdebug]

zend_extension = "D:/wamp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll"

xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = xdebug
xdebug.remote_log = "D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 0
xdebug.trace_format = 0
```

I followed almost all tutorial on google (also on stackoverflow) and I think configuration seems to be correct. So what would be the issue?

If you want more information about configuration please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that port in your IDE conforms with the one set in php.ini

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm using XAMPP in Windows 7 and have not being able to run debug either. Furthermore, I have run into the same problem when using Ubuntu, so it is not a windows 7 or WAMP isolated problem for sure.

Comment: The best way would be to check what is in "D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log" - that log file is there for a reason!

Comment: This worked for me. I set the port to 9001 in netbeans. Furthermore, I would recommend changing "xdebug.idekey = xdebug" to  "xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug" in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem `waiting for connection` but there I found a very good step by step tutorial [here](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue) which solved mine. 
Hope this link be also helpful for you.